# Associative arrays: I'm trying to figure out what's happening in this snippet of code

Tags: perl

So, I'm fairly new to perl and want to understand the underlying concepts illustrated in the following code:

```
while (my ($key,$val)=each%{$vec1}){
    $num += $val*($$vec2{$key} || 0);
}
```

Where vec1, vec2 are associative arrays.  I especially want to understand what's going on with:

```
each%{$vec1} and $$vec2{$key}
```

I knew that it was something to do with referencing/dereferencing hashes, so I found this link:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-hash-reference/, but I don't really understand what's going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I just found this link, which explains it much better than the other one: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlsub.htm#References

Comment: Change `sub getGlobalName` to `sub getGlobalName :lvalue` in your deleted question...

Comment: You will more commonly see `$$vec2{$key}` written as `$vec2->{$key}`. In fact I'd be rather suspicious of the abilities of a Perl programmer who used the first form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$vec1` is a reference to a hash. `%{$vec1}` gets this hash. Applying `each` to a hash gives the (key, value) pairs on subsequent calls. [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)

`$vec2{$key}` is the value in hash `vec2` for key `$key`. This value is itself a reference, which is dereferenced by the additional $

Answer (score 1):

> **`each%{$vec1}`**

`$vec1` is a scalar hash reference.

`%{$vec1}` dereferencing it.

finally, `each%{$vec1}` returns `key-value` pair.

---

> **$$vec2{$key}**

`$key` is a `key` of hash `$vec2`.

Hence, `$vec2{$key}` should be the `value` of key `$key`

Finally, `$$vec2{$key}` is a dereferencing a reference of scalar `$vec2{$key}`.

Answer (score 0):

`each%{$vec1}`

$vect is a reference to a hash, and `each` iterates over a hash, so you need to de-reference if with `%{$vec1}` syntax. `each` returns a 2-element list consisting of the key and value for the next element of a hash.

`$$vec2{$key}`

We don't see the definition of $vec2 variable, and the kind of elements you are storing on it, 
but it seems like this is a hash `%vec2`, storing scalar references to numbers